# What is ':-!!' in C?

Tags: c, linux, macros, operators

I bumped into this strange macro code in [`/usr/include/linux/kernel.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ff2d8b19a3a62559afba1c53360c8577a7697714/include/linux/kernel.h#L677-L682):

```
/* Force a compilation error if condition is true, but also produce a
   result (of value 0 and type size_t), so the expression can be used
   e.g. in a structure initializer (or where-ever else comma expressions
   aren't permitted). */
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_NULL(e) ((void *)sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
```

What does `:-!!` do?

---

*Update: In recent times, the macro has been moved to [`/usr/include/linux/build_bug.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/382d4cd1847517ffcb1800fd462b625db7b2ebea/include/linux/build_bug.h#L10-L16)*

Comment: - Unary minus <br />
! Logical NOT <br />
inverse not not of the given Integer e
so the variable can either be 0 or 1.

Comment: git blame tells us that this particular form of static assertion was [introduced by Jan Beulich in 8c87df4](https://github.com/mirrors/linux-2.6/commit/8c87df457cb58fe75b9b893007917cf8095660a0). Obviously he had good reasons to do it (see the commit message).

Comment: Almost goes without saying that the bitfield created is an anonymous one. This is in the same spirit as C++ template meta-programming, i.e. have things happen at compile time that can be checked at compile time.

Comment: Wait, I thought the arguments of `sizeof` are not evaluated. Is that wrong in this case? If so, why? Because it's a macro?

Comment: @cpcloud, `sizeof` does "evaluate" the type, just not the value. Its the type thats invalid in this case.

Comment: Several of the answers mention that `:0` gives a zero-sized anonymous bit-field, and therefore a zero-sized struct. That's not quite true; in standard C, `:0` is not any kind of field declaration (you can't give it a name) but rather a directive to start the _next_ bit-field on the next word boundary (typically `int` but not necessarily). It doesn't normally have any significance unless used between two (otherwise adjacent) bit-field declarations. The resulting struct is zero-sized because it contains _no_ declarations; and that of course is a gcc extension.

Answer (score 1807, accepted):

This is, in effect, **a way to check whether the expression e can be evaluated to be 0, and if not, to fail the build**.

The macro is somewhat misnamed; it should be something more like `BUILD_BUG_OR_ZERO`, rather than `...ON_ZERO`. (There have been **[occasional discussions about whether this is a confusing name](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0703.1/1546.html)**.)

You should read the expression like this:

```
sizeof(struct { int: -!!(e); }))
```

1. `(e)`: Compute expression `e`.
2. `!!(e)`: Logically negate twice: `0` if `e == 0`; otherwise `1`.
3. `-!!(e)`: Numerically negate the expression from step 2: `0` if it was `0`; otherwise `-1`.
4. `struct{int: -!!(0);} --> struct{int: 0;}`: If it was zero, then we declare a struct with an anonymous integer bitfield that has width zero. Everything is fine and we proceed as normal.
5. `struct{int: -!!(1);} --> struct{int: -1;}`: On the other hand, if it *isn't* zero, then it will be some negative number. Declaring any bitfield with *negative* width is a compilation error.

So we'll either wind up with a bitfield that has width 0 in a struct, which is fine, or a bitfield with negative width, which is a compilation error. Then we take `sizeof` that field, so we get a `size_t` with the appropriate width (which will be zero in the case where `e` is zero).

---

Some people have asked: **Why not just use an `assert`?**

[keithmo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9230305/75170) here has a good response:

> These macros implement a compile-time test, while assert() is a run-time test.

Exactly right. You don't want to detect problems in your *kernel* at runtime that could have been caught earlier! It's a critical piece of the operating system. To whatever extent problems can be detected at compile time, so much the better.

Comment: So how does this macro get used, i.e. what value or expression for `e` is used?

Comment: @weston Lots of different places. **[See for yourself!](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux%2Fkernel%2Fgit%2Ftorvalds%2Flinux.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO)**

Comment: recent variants of C++ or C standards have something like `static_assert` for related purposes.

Comment: @Basile: With recent variants of C++ you should use template metaprogramming :)

Comment: @Lundin - #error would require use of 3 lines of code #if/#error/#endif, and would only work for evaluations accessible to the pre-processor.  This hack works for any evaluation accessible to the compiler.

Comment: The Linux kernel does not use C++, at least not while Linus is still alive.

Comment: this is why static asserts have been introduced in D

Comment: re: static_assert, this is not available everywhere Linux builds.

Comment: "You don't want to detect *any* problems at runtime that could have been caught earlier!" Fixed that for you.

Comment: The another important point of this test is whether the expression can be evaluated at the compile time, the build would fail if it couldn't be.

Comment: @Dolda2000: "*Boolean expressions in C are defined to always evaluate to zero or one*" -- Not exactly. The *operators* that yield "logically  boolean" results (`!`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`, `&&`, `||`) always yield 0 or 1. Other expressions may yield results that may be used as a conditions, but are merely zero or non-zero; for example, `isdigit(c)`, where `c` is a digit, can yield *any* non-zero value (which is then treated as true in a condition).

Comment: Since when is `sizeof` any type allowed to be zero?  That violates the uniqueness of addresses of array elements.  (And this is C, so let's not get into empty base class optimization, which still doesn't result in any object having zero size)

Comment: @BenVoigt The C standard does not allow zero-size types. The Linux kernel relies on numerous `gcc` compiler extensions that aren't part of the standard. See, e.g., here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143417/why-is-linux-kernel-coded-using-non-standard-c-gcc-specific-features

Comment: @John: I understand that the kernel uses gcc extensions.  But extensions merely give meaning to invalid code.  If a compiler changes the meaning of valid code, that's a bug.

Comment: I've been doing C programming for a while, and haven't seen this "bit field" functionality. So for anyone in same position, here's a good tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm

Comment: Quick note about the name. It's called `...ON_ZERO` because it's a derivative of `BUG_ON`, a macro that's essentially an assertion. `BUG_ON(foo)` means "it's a bug if `foo` is true" (at runtime). Conversely, `BUILD_BUG_ON` is a static assertion (checked at build time), and finally `BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO` is exactly the same, except that the whole thing is an expression equal to `(size_t)0`, as the comment in the question states.

Comment: @Xion: thanks for that explanation. But I'll confess that I find the name `BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO` extremely confusing and wish I didn't need to  search the internet to understand how it's used.  I'm not sure what name would work for everyone, but as far as I'm concerned I wish the name `BUILD_BUG_OR_ZERO` had been used.

Comment: Anyway we can't use these macro for a variable. right? `error: bit-field ‘<anonymous>’ width not an integer constant` Its allowing only constants. So, what's the use?

Comment: why to do double negation, because end result of double negation is same as original value.

Comment: @Dinesh You are confused with `~`.  `!` only yields 0 or 1.

Comment: I think the answer should mention that `struct { int :0}` is `undefined behaviour` according to the C standard. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297095/practical-use-of-zero-length-bitfields#12918937

Comment: There is an additional closing parenthesis in the last which belonged to the macro, in case someone is wondering that why an extra closing parenthesis.
PS - I tried to edit, but edit should be at least 6 characters long.

Comment: @Hejazzman re: static_assert,  You could use static_assert like this, right? `#if (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 201100L)
 #include <assert.h>
#else
 #define static_assert(e, txt) BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e)
#endif`

Answer (score 275):

The `:` is a bitfield. As for `!!`, that is [logical double negation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code) and so returns `0` for false or `1` for true. And the `-` is a minus sign, i.e. arithmetic negation.

It's all just a trick to get the compiler to barf on invalid inputs.

Consider `BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO`. When `-!!(e)` evaluates to a negative value, that produces a compile error. Otherwise `-!!(e)` evaluates to 0,  and a 0 width bitfield has size of 0. And hence the macro evaluates to a `size_t` with value 0.

The name is weak in my view because the build in fact fails when the input is *not* zero.

`BUILD_BUG_ON_NULL` is very similar, but yields a pointer rather than an `int`.

Comment: is `sizeof(struct { int:0; })` strictly conforming?

Comment: Why would the result in general be `0`? A `struct` with only an empty bitfield, true, but I don't think that struct with size 0 are allowed.   E.g if you'd create an array of that type, the individual array elements still must have different addresses, no?

Comment: they actually don't care as as they use GNU extensions, they disable strict aliasing rule and don't consider integer overflows as UB. But I was wondering if this is strictly conforming C.

Comment: @ouah regarding unnamed zero length bitfields, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297095/practical-use-of-zero-length-bitfields#4297110

Comment: @DavidHeffernan interesting, but the quote is from C++ standard not C

Comment: size 0 bit fields are used for forcing alignment.

Comment: @ouah Pretty much identical text is present in the C standard also.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan actually C allows unamed bit-field of `0` width, but not if there no other named member in the structure. `(C99, 6.7.2.1p2) "If the struct-declaration-list contains no named members, the behavior is undefined."` So for example `sizeof (struct {int a:1; int:0;})` is strictly conforming but `sizeof(struct { int:0; })` is not (undefined behavior).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: can you, please, detaliate, why the result of !!(e) is either 0 or 1 (and no other non-zero number)? I miss that part. What happens to the other bits in original e that are negated twice? They do not retrieve their original values? Thank you.

Comment: @axeoth `!` is *logical* negation and '~' is *bitwise* negation. So we are dealing here with logical negation. The logical negation operator evaluates to either 0 or 1.

Comment: @JensGustedt: It would not be practical to uphold for objects of zero size the same guarantees that would apply to objects of non-zero size, but the same is true of real zero as well.  There should have been no problem saying that if p and q are pointers to zero-size type, adding or subtracting any value from p will yield p, and p-q will yield 0 if p==q and an Unspecified Value in all other cases. The *only* downside I can see would be that it would render useless code which attempts to use arrays of size zero (rather than -1) to force compiler errors when required conditions don't hold.

Answer (score 177):

Some people seem to be confusing these macros with `assert()`.

These macros implement a compile-time test, while `assert()` is a runtime test.

### Update:

As of C11, the [`_Static_assert()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3385515/16217248) keyword is available to create compile time tests, and should be used unless code is being written for old compilers.

Answer (score 58):

Well, I am quite surprised that the alternatives to this syntax have not been mentioned.  Another common (but older) mechanism is to call a function that isn't defined and rely on the optimizer to compile-out the function call if your assertion is correct.

```
#define MY_COMPILETIME_ASSERT(test)              \
    do {                                         \
        extern void you_did_something_bad(void); \
        if (!(test))                             \
            you_did_something_bad(void);         \
    } while (0)
```

While this mechanism works (as long as optimizations are enabled) it has the downside of not reporting an error until you link, at which time it fails to find the definition for the function you_did_something_bad().  That's why kernel developers starting using tricks like the negative sized bit-field widths and the negative-sized arrays (the later of which stopped breaking builds in GCC 4.4).

In sympathy for the need for compile-time assertions, GCC 4.3 introduced the [`error` function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bflatten_007d-function-attribute-2586) that allows you to extend upon this older concept, but generate a compile-time error with a message of your choosing -- no more cryptic "negative sized array" error messages!

```
#define MAKE_SURE_THIS_IS_FIVE(number)                          \
    do {                                                        \
        extern void this_isnt_five(void) __attribute__((error(  \
                "I asked for five and you gave me " #number))); \
        if ((number) != 5)                                      \
            this_isnt_five();                                   \
    } while (0)
```

In fact, as of Linux 3.9, we now have a macro called [`compiletime_assert`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/compiler.h?id=9e895ace5d82df8929b16f58e9f515f6d54ab82d#n337) which uses this feature and most of the macros in [`bug.h`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/bug.h?id=9e895ace5d82df8929b16f58e9f515f6d54ab82d) have been updated accordingly.  Still, this macro can't be used as an initializer.  However, using by [*statement expressions*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) (another GCC C-extension), you can!

```
#define ANY_NUMBER_BUT_FIVE(number)                           \
    ({                                                        \
        typeof(number) n = (number);                          \
        extern void this_number_is_five(void) __attribute__(( \
                error("I told you not to give me a five!"))); \
        if (n == 5)                                           \
            this_number_is_five();                            \
        n;                                                    \
    })
```

This macro will evaluate its parameter exactly once (in case it has side-effects) and create a compile-time error that says "I told you not to give me a five!" if the expression evaluates to five or is not a compile-time constant.

So why aren't we using this instead of negative-sized bit-fields? Alas, there are currently many restrictions of the use of statement expressions, including their use as constant initializers (for enum constants, bit-field width, etc.) even if the statement expression is completely constant its self (i.e., can be fully evaluated at compile-time and otherwise passes the [`__builtin_constant_p()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fconstant_005fp-3386) test).  Further, they cannot be used outside of a function body.

Hopefully, GCC will amend these shortcomings soon and allow constant statement expressions to be used as constant initializers.  The challenge here is the language specification defining what is a legal constant expression.  C++11 added the constexpr keyword for just this type or thing, but no counterpart exists in C11.  While C11 did get static assertions, which will solve part of this problem, it wont solve all of these shortcomings.  So I hope that gcc can make a constexpr functionality available as an extension via -std=gnuc99 & -std=gnuc11 or some such and allow its use on statement expressions et. al.

Comment: All of your solutions are NOT alternatives. The comment above the macro is pretty clear "`so the expression can be used e.g. in a structure initializer (or where-ever else comma expressions aren't permitted).`" The macro returns an expression of type `size_t`

Comment: @Wiz Yes, I am aware of this.  Perhaps this was a bit verbose and maybe I need to re-visit my wording, but my point was to explore the various mechanisms for static assertions and show why we're still using negative sized bitfields.  In short, if we get a mechanism for constant statement expression, we will have other options open.

Comment: Anyway we can't use these macro for a variable. right? `error: bit-field ‘<anonymous>’ width not an integer constant` Its allowing only constants. So, what's the use?

Comment: @Karthik Search the sources of the Linux kernel to see why it's used.

Answer (score 39):

It's creating a size `0` bitfield if the condition is false, but a size `-1` (`-!!1`) bitfield if the condition is true/non-zero.  In the former case, there is no error and the struct is initialized with an int member.  In the latter case, there is a compile error (and no such thing as a size `-1` bitfield is created, of course).

Comment: Actually it's returning a `size_t` with value 0 in case the condition is true.