# Expansion of module_param() macro: a struct with a single member or a bitfield?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, sizeof, bit-fields

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “:-!!” in C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229601/what-is-in-c-code)

The linux kernel `module_param()` macro expands into several instructions, some of them using numbers (sizes) that are calculated as follow (I only paste here relevant code):

`sizeof(struct { int:- ! !(((00400|00040|00004)) < 0 || ((00400|00040|00004)) > 0777 || (((00400|00040|00004)) & 2)); })`

Could somebody enlighten me what is that `int:- ! !(NUMBER)` doing?

Actually, I have several questions:
1) why define a struct with a single member?
2) why do not name that member? (or is the member's name... "int", just like the type?)
3) what is the meaning of that `int:- ! !(NUMBER)` expression? Is that a struct field? A bitfield?
4) what is the meaning and the final result of the above sizeof()?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's an anonymous bit field.

Comment: it's a compile time check your questions are answered here [What is “:-!!” in C code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229601/what-is-in-c-code)

Comment: Pondering the meaning of this obfuscated code is most likely a big waste of time. To sum it up: it is a very disturbed person's way of implementing `static_assert` using bitwise operators on octal numbers, while relying on non-standard, gcc-specific features.

Comment: @Lundin `static_assert` ? isn't that c++11 ?

Comment: What is this non-standard, please? @Lundin

Comment: @mux: Thank You, please post an answer in order for me to accept it.

Comment: @Lundin: I need to understand what the code does as one of my static analysis tools does not, so I have to manually correct that.

Comment: @axeoth there's no need to duplicate an answer, the question linked has plenty of good answers and comments :)

Comment: @axeoth Since the code is a complete mess and also relies on non-standard C, it will not pass any half-decent static analysis tool.