# macros defined in linux kernel.h file

Tags: c++, c, linux, macros

On stack overflow I ran into a question [What is ":-!!" in C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229601/what-is-in-c-code)

```
> #define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
> #define BUILD_BUG_ON_NULL(e) ((void *)sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
```

out of curiosity I want to know how can I use these kind of macros ?

```
int main()
{
    BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(0);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code it gives an error that type name is not allowed.

EDIT :
the code compiles on linux using gcc but fails on visual studio

Comment: I think that is the purpose of these macros: to give compilation error on ZERO or NULL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229601/what-is-in-c-code [edit:] What isn't already answered there?

Comment: I want to know how to use it in code ..

Comment: http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg42642.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229793/680982) carefully:

> The macro is somewhat misnamed; it should be something more like
>   `BUILD_BUG_OR_ZERO`, rather than `...ON_ZERO`

So it fails to compile when the parameter is nonzero:

```
int main()
{
    BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(1);
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/TI97r3

---

As for a practical usage:

```
int main()
{
    BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(sizeof(int) != 4); // we need int to be 4 bytes, stop compilation otherwise
    return 0;
}
```

---

As for C++: this is a C construct that does not compile in C++ at all.

In C++11 you can use a `static_assert` instead.

Comment: Of course, in C++, you could redefine the macro to a suitable `static_assert`.

Comment: I think _UNLESS_ZERO would be even better than _OR_ZERO

Comment: just for the records `static_assert` is common between C++11 and C11.

Comment: `static_assert` isn't as flexible and can't always be used as a substitute. `BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO` also returns an expression (`(size_t)0`), so it can be used in many (tricky, but highly useful) macro definitions, as well as just as a statement.

See, for example, the `ARRAY_SIZE` and `__must_be_array` macros in `include/linux/kernel.h`.