# Why does double negation force values to become a bool?

Tags: c++, c

If x was a 4 bit word like 1010, and you did the operation !!x,

- Wouldn't the first !x return 0101,
- And the second !(!x) return 1010?

Rather it returns ...0001 or ...0000. Why is this?

Comment: Maybe figure out what single negation does first?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229601/what-is-in-c-code (I swear there was a better question like this but can't find it at the moment..)

Comment: you are confusing `!` and `~`

Comment: First `!` turns any non-zero value into `false`, second `!` makes it `true` (and vice versa)

Comment: In C, "double negation force values to become a bool" is not quite correct.  `!` result is an `int`, not a `bool`, with a value of 0 or 1.

Answer (score 7):

In C, `!x` is either 1 or 0, So `!!x` is a "collapse to 0 or 1 operator" in the sense that any non-zero number is mapped to 1, and 0 stays as it is. This *can* be useful on occasions.

In C++, `!x` is a `bool` type, So `!!x` is a "collapse to false or true operator" in the sense that any non-zero number is mapped to `true`, and zero is mapped to `false`.

Comment: @Adrian I scrapped the c#. Perhaps you can answer for that one.

Comment: The question does not really apply to c# anyway. C# does not have implicit integer to bool conversion.

Comment: @Adrian Saved by the retagging!

Comment: Why would you not simply do `(bool)x` or `(_Bool)x`?

Comment: @Ayxan: That changes the type of the expression.

Comment: @Bat `!!x` does too in C++. Also, does it ever matter in C?

Answer (score 6):

The `!` operator performs logical negation.  If its argument is non-zero, it results in 0.  If its argument is 0, it results in 1.

What you're describing is the **bitwise complement operator**, denoted by `~`.

These are both described in section 6.5.3.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *4* The result of the `~` operator is the bitwise complement of its (promoted) operand (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only
>   if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set). The
>   integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has
>   the promoted type. If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the
>   expression `~E` is equivalent to the maximum value representable in
>   that type minus `E`.
>
> *5* The result of the logical negation operator `!` is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
>   compares equal to 0. The result has type `int`. The expression `!E` is
>   equivalent to `(0==E)`.

Comment: I think C's `!` can be better described as a "!=0" operator.  When applied to logical values it negates them, but it may also be applied to other types such as floating-point values or pointers.

Answer (score 2):

`!` is a boolean operator, so it will convert the number into a bool (any non-zero value is `true`, zero is always `false`). That other `!` inverts the bool.

Comment: In C (as post is dual tagged - sigh), `!` result is not a `bool`, but an `int`.

Comment: Yes, in C there are no `bool`s (not like `true`/`false`) but it's an `int` value. (either `0` or `1`) but in C++ and C# it is a `bool`

Comment: Disagree with "in C there are no bools (not like true/false)". Since C99, C has a boolean type `_Bool` (aka `bool` via `<stdbool.h>`).  The C return type of `!` still remains `int`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that.

Comment: Posts tagged C _and_ C++ unfortunately create issues like this - not your fault.